# TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting python

Tags: python

The program should print the entries which are divided into three without the remainder. The problem is "TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting python " in the bottom

```
numbers = [ ]
while True:
    inputNumber = (input("Enter a number if you want to terminate this, please tap on 'q' : "))
    if inputNumber == "q":
        break    
    numbers.append(inputNumber)
    


sum = 0
for i in numbers:
    sum+=int(i)

print("Sum of the inputs : ", sum)

#unexecutable lines  
for i in numbers:
    if(i%3 == 0):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Where you have `i%3`, `i` is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` is in string format.

Hence type cast it to `int` before carrying out calculation:

```
#unexecutable lines  
for i in numbers:
    if(int(i)%3 == 0):
        print(i)
```